# Tried to set the width of a texttilate jquery loaded animation, doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, width

I got an animation from here: http://codepen.io/jschr/pen/GaJCi

I am using it in my project.

```css
#content {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 700px;
}

#animation {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 20;
 width: 1000px;
 height:50px;
 top: 600px;
 left: 350px;
}

#animation2 {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 20;
 width: 1000px;
 height:50px;
 top: -25px;
 left: 340px;
}

Inside the animation.css:

h1 {
  position: absolute;
  font: 12vmin/12vmin 'Special Elite', cursive;
  left: 0;
  top: 30%;
  margin-top: -4vmin;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2vmin 0;
  text-shadow: 0.15vmin 0.15vmin rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
In the main html:
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
 <div id="animation"></div>​
 <script>
       $("#animation").html('<object data="./animation/animation.htm">');
 </script>
 <div id="animation2"></div>​
 <script>
       $("#animation2").html('<object data="./animation/animation2.htm">');
 </script>
</div>
And the animations witch i load into te main html:

<head>
   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Special+Elite" rel="stylesheet"> 
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="animate.css" charset="utf-8" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="animation.css" charset="utf-8" />
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="jquery.lettering.js"></script>
   <script src="jquery.fittext.js"></script>
   <script src="jquery.textillate.js"></script>
   
   
</head>
  
 <body>
 <h1 class="tlt">Hello to my website and welcome</h1>
<script>
$('.tlt').textillate({ 
  in: { effect: 'splat' },
  out: { effect:'hinge', sync: true },
  loop: true
});
</script>
 </body>

The second animation looks almost same.
```

What i want is the ability to set the width, to be able to see the whole phrase with the font almost at 30px. The problem is, the first animation i am able to set the font at 8vmin while the second animation i come to 12vmin to get the phrases as one string. If i make it bigger, it will break to more strings or even cut the phrase, depends were i try to set the width. I saw the animation does inject spans into my html and they are width 300, while i need almost width 700. I was trying to find away online also tried to change my css with no result. I also tried to catch the span injection and make it larger, but not helped so fare. Still hope to find a solution to this. If someone knows how, please show me, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
I found out, i can this:

<script>
       $("#animation").html('<object data="./animation/animation.htm">');
 </script>

simply to this:

<script>
       $("#animation").html('<object width="600px" data="./animation/animation.htm">');
 </script>

And this is how it worked for me, it increased the width inside the loaded object data, thanks anyway.
```